# SQL Server distinct query with two columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My tables are:

**tblProduct**

```
male| female| Brand_ID
```

and

**tblBrands**

```
Brand_ID| Brand_Name
```

My query is here:

```
Select distinct   
    a.Male, a.Female, b.Brand_Name 
from 
    tblProduct as a 
inner join
    tblBrands as b on b.Brand_ID = a.Brand_ID
```

This query returns this output:

```
Male    Female  Brand_Name
----------------------------------
 1       0        ABC
 0       1        ABC
 1       0        ABC
 1       0        PQR
 1       0        PQR
 0       1        PQR
 0       1        XYZ
 0       1        XYZ
```

But I want this output shown below - what should I do for to get this?

```
Male    Female  Brand_Name
 ----------------------------------
 1       1        ABC
 1       1        PQR
 0       1        XYZ
```

There check is if the brand XYZ is for male or female if is a male bit is true and female bit is true is show XYZ 1 1 or if female or male present according to that show XYZ 1 0 or XYZ 0 1

Comment: Please Paste the tables input

Comment: I add my table parameter in question

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected output row for `Brand_Name = 'xyz'`? There is no record where `Male = 1`.

Comment: Please answxer honeyBadger's comment. How did you got to 1  0  XYZ ?

Comment: there check is if the brand  XYZ   is for male or female if is a male bit is true and female bit is true is show XYZ 1 1 or if female or male present according to that show XYZ 1 0 or XYZ 0 1

Comment: Can you elaborate this better in your question please. I still dont understand how you got to 1  0  XYZ

Comment: So the last record should be 0  1  XYZ and not 1  0  XYZ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` clause will solve your problem

```
Select   
  Max(cast(a.Male as int)) as Male  , 
  Max(cast(a.Female as int)) as Female,
  b.Brand_Name 
from tblProduct as a inner join
tblBrands as b on b.Brand_ID = a.Brand_ID
group by b.Brand_Name
```

Comment: 1 and 0 is bit not number

Comment: 1       0        XYZ this query doesn't give last tuple

Comment: @Tushar please see updated solution. Solves your bit problem. Please answer the question about last record

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that `Male` and `Female` columns are of type `bit` then, this is how you can write your query **without** needing `MAX` and `CAST` functions:

```
 select (case when ((select count(*) from tblProduct a where a.Male=1 and a.Brand_ID=b.Brand_ID) > 0) then 1 else 0 end) Male,
        (case when ((select count(*) from tblProduct a where a.Female=1 and a.Brand_ID=b.Brand_ID) > 0) then 1 else 0 end) Female
        ,b.Brand_Name
 from tblProduct as a inner join
 tblBrand as b on b.Brand_ID = a.Brand_ID
 group by b.Brand_Name,b.Brand_ID
```